# Unable to clone private repository github : Authentication failed

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-clone, private-repository

I have created a private repo in github and when I am trying to clone it using cmd (git), I am prompted with github window where I enter my username and password. It says login failed in the cmd and then asks username/password in the cmd. I enter the credentials again and press enter. I get error like **fatal: Authentication failed for**

I performed the above operation using https.
when I tried with ssh, i get this error
***git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.***

How can I clone this private repository?

Comment: Have you tried using SSH?

Comment: yes @Joe . I have edited the question by adding the error i am getting while trying with ssh

Comment: Did you setup your key locally and on github? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Github no longer supports basic account credentials (username and password). You have to generate a personal access token to proceed.
follow these steps here: [Generate Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)

I use Webstorm IDE and it made this very easy to fix. I hope this works for you.

Comment: I generated the personal access token and used it in place of password in cmd. It worked. thanks

Comment: You're welcome @kakashiOfSharingan